# How do I discover a Chromecast device using Android?

Tags: android, google-cast

I'd like to discover a Chromecast device and adjust the volume.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Get a device
2. Get your [device whitelisted](https://developers.google.com/cast/whitelisting) (you'll need the device serial #, and a URL for your HTML5 receiver)
3. You'll be sent two APPID (development / production)
4. In your development environment make sure to update to Android Support Library v18
5. You'll be using [MediaRouter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/mediarouter/package-summary.html)
6. Initialize

```
import com.google.cast.CastContext;     
Context applicationContext = …; CastContext castContext = new
CastContext(applicationContext);
```

- You'll need a **MediaRouteButton**

```
< android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
  android:id="@+id/media_route_button"
  android:mediaRouteTypes="user"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:visibility="visible" />
```

```
import com.google.cast.CastContext; 
import com.google.cast.CastDevice;
import com.google.cast.MediaRouteAdapter; 
import com.google.cast.MediaRouteHelper; 
import com.google.cast.MediaRouteStateChangeListener;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter;
import android.support.v7.media.MediaRouter.RouteInfo; 

public class MyCastActivity extends FragmentActivity implements MediaRouteAdapter {
     private MediaRouteButton mMediaRouteButton;
     private MediaRouter mMediaRouter;
     private MediaRouteSelector mMediaRouteSelector;
     private MediaRouter.Callback mMediaRouterCallback;
     private CastDevice mSelectedDevice;
     private MediaRouteStateChangeListener mRouteStateListener;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.my_cast_activity);
         mMediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton) findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
```

- Construct a **`CastContext`**.

```
mCastContext = new CastContext(getApplicationContext());
```

- Register the **`MinimalCastMediaRouteProvider`** by calling
   **`MediaRouteHelper.registerMinimalMediaRouteProvider`**(), passing an
   object that implements the **`MediaRouteAdapter`** interface.

```
MediaRouteHelper.registerMinimalMediaRouteProvider(mCastContext, this);
mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

- Construct a **`MediaRouteSelector`** by calling
  **`MediaRouteHelper.buildMediaRouteSelector()`**. There are two forms of
  this method: the first takes no parameters and the second takes a
  receiver application name and/or a list of message protocols. This
  latter form is used to perform device filtering equivalent to that
  done by the SDK’s **`ApplicationSupportFilterListener`**.

```
mMediaRouteSelector = MediaRouteHelper.buildMediaRouteSelector( MediaRouteHelper.CATEGORY_CAST);
```

- Assign the MediaRouteSelector to the MediaRouteButton.

```
mMediaRouteButton.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);
```

- Implement a `MediaRouter.Callback` and add it to the `MediaRouter`,
  passing **`CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY`** to the `MediaRouter` to
  initiate discovery. When the user selects or deselects a route in the
  GUI picker, the corresponding method on this callback interface will
  be invoked.

> ```
>     mMediaRouterCallback = new MyMediaRouterCallback();
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onStart() {
>    super.onStart();
>     mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
>         MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onStop() {
>     mMediaRouter.removeCallback(mMediaRouterCallback);
>     super.onStop();
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onDestroy() {
>     MediaRouteHelper.unregisterMediaRouteProvider(mCastContext);
>     mCastContext.dispose();
>     super.onDestroy();
> }
> ```

- In the `MediaRouter.Callback`’s **`onRouteSelected()`** callback, make a call
  to **`MediaRouteHelper.requestCastDeviceForRoute()`** to obtain a
  CastDevice object for the selected media route, as well as the
  **`MediaRouteStateChangeListener`** that will need to be notified whenever
  route volume or connecting state changes.

> ```
> private class MyMediaRouterCallback extends MediaRouter.Callback {
>     @Override
>     public void onRouteSelected(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo route) {
>         MediaRouteHelper.requestCastDeviceForRoute(route);
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onRouteUnselected(MediaRouter router, RouteInfo route) {
>         mSelectedDevice = null;
>         mRouteStateListener = null;
>     }
> }
>
> // MediaRouteAdapter implementation
>
> @Override
> public void onDeviceAvailable(CastDevice device,
>         MediaRouteStateChangeListener listener) {
>     mSelectedDevice = device;
>     mRouteStateListener = listener;
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onSetVolume(double volume) {
>     // Handle volume change.
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onUpdateVolume(double delta) {
>     // Handle volume change.
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Can I discover a device without using v18 libraries, and modifying the mediarouter source to make it dependent on ActionBarSherlock rather than AppCompat? So far it hasn't worked, but I'm wondering if there is something else missing.

Comment: Nope - It doesn't work w/ ActionBarSherlock - at least last time I checked it.

Comment: I have follow all these steps... but still unable to cast on TV... Device is not found...  I have confusion.... I am working on sender app so should I need reciver device whitelisted and where I have to put App ID if I whitelist my device... kindly kindly kindly help me out. stuck on it more than 2 days. @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel

Comment: In Setup, did you [x] send your serial # to google.  You can test by <ip of Chromecast>:9222

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel... could u please guide me what should the url file contain??

Comment: The URL for your Receiver is usually something like mysite.com/cast/receiver.html  -- A HTML5 application that plays your content.  The load url should be the content you want played on the Chromecast

Comment: Is this still accurate for the official Cast SDK?  The `CastContext` class seems to have vanished.

Comment: This is old, the v2 SDK replaces it.