# Not able to discover chromecast device in android

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromecast

I am working with chromecast in android. I did almost every thing(according to me.)

1. I have whitelisted my chromecast Device.
2. Got AppID.

   But still I am unbable to discover my chromecast device. I have follow this link [How do I discover a Chromecast device using Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842845/how-do-i-discover-a-chromecast-device-using-android) as well as this https://developers.google.com/cast/cast_2nd-screen_app_tutorial. In chromecast app I have also  checked this box **Send this Chromecast's serial number when checking for update**. What I am missing I cant understand.

Comment: Please send us an email on chromecast-updates@google.com so we can look into your issue. In your email, please include your developer id, your app id, your url and your device's serial number, thanks.

Comment: @Ali_Nadaff We are also having issue with the Updates of Chromecast here in Pakistan. And have somehow blocked that. Could you Please guide us in that issue?