# Discover chromecast devices

Tags: chromecast

I did everything verbatim on this sample ([How do I discover a Chromecast device using Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842845/how-do-i-discover-a-chromecast-device-using-android)).

The chromecast icon turns to white on indicating there are devices available.

When I pressed it, the application unfortunately stops.

What can be going wrong? The only step so far I want to achieve is list all available devices.

Cheers!

Comment: `the application unfortunately stops` In what way? Crashes? Exits gracefully? What do your logs say? What happens when you're debugging this?

Comment: And what's the code it's executing when it stops?

Comment: You may wish to take a look at the sample code at github.com/googlecast